# mongo db how to write a function in an query maybe aggregation?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

The question is Calculate the average age of the users who have more than 3 strengths listed.

One of the data is like this :

```
{
    "_id" : 1.0,
    "user_id" : "jshaw0",
    "first_name" : "Judy",
    "last_name" : "Shaw",
    "email" : "jshaw0@merriam-webster.com",
    "age" : 39.0,
    "status" : "disabled",
    "join_date" : "2016-09-05",
    "last_login_date" : "2016-09-30 23:59:36 -0400",
    "address" : {
        "city" : "Deskle",
        "province" : "PEI"
    },
    "strengths" : [ 
        "star schema", 
        "dw planning", 
        "sql", 
        "mongo queries"
    ],
    "courses" : [ 
        {
            "code" : "CSIS2300",
            "total_questions" : 118.0,
            "correct_answers" : 107.0,
            "incorect_answers" : 11.0
        }, 
        {
            "code" : "CSIS3300",
            "total_questions" : 101.0,
            "correct_answers" : 34.0,
            "incorect_answers" : 67.0
        }
    ]
}
```

I know I need to count how many strengths this data has, and then set it to `$gt`, and then calculate the average age.
However, I don't know how to write 2 function which are count and average in one query. Do I need to use aggregation, if so, how?

Thanks so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`$redact`](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/operator/aggregation/redact/) to match your array size  & [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) to calculate the average :

```
db.collection.aggregate([{
    "$redact": {
        "$cond": [
            { "$gt": [{ "$size": "$strengths" }, 3] },
            "$$KEEP",
            "$$PRUNE"
        ]
    }
}, {
    $group: {
        _id: 1,
        average: { $avg: "$age" }
    }
}])
```

The `$redact` part match the size of `strenghs` array greater than 3, it will `$$KEEP` record that match this condition otherwise `$$PRUNE` the record that don't match. Check [`$redact` documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/operator/aggregation/redact/)

The `$group` just perform an average with [`$avg`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/avg/)